# Using backticks and operators in apply family functions

Tags: r, dataframe, operators, apply

I saw in a recent answer an apply family function with assignments built-in and can't generalize it.

```
lst <- list(a=1, b=2:3)
lst
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2 3
```

This can't yet be made into a data.frame because of the unequal lengths. But by coercing the max length to the list, it works:

```
data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
   a b
1  1 2
2 NA 3
```

That works. But I've never used arrow assignments in apply functions. I tried to understand it by generalizing like:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) length(x) <- max(lengths(lst)))
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 2
```

That's not the correct output. Nor is

```
lapply(lst, function(x) length(x) <- max(lengths(x)))
 Error in lengths(x) : 'x' must be a list
```

This would be a useful technique to understand well. Is there a way to express the assignment in the anonymous function form?

Comment: You are not returning `x`.  i.e. `lapply(lst, function(x) {length(x) <- max(lengths(lst)); x})`

Comment: Nice. So `lapply(a, 'func1<-', func2(a)` is the same as `lapply(a, function(x) {func1(x) <- func2(a); x`?

Comment: It should be the same for functions that can be assigned.

Comment: @akrun post that as an answer so it can be accepted, and people can find it in the future

Comment: Wrong tag: you want to use [tag:data.frame]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using anonymous functions, we are returning only the value of that function, and not the value of 'x'.  We have to specify `return(x)` or simply `x`.

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {
                  length(x) <- max(lengths(lst))
                  x})
#$a
#[1]  1 NA

#$b
#[1] 2 3
```